# Logcat says "Unknown Window Type"

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

I'm trying to debug my android app, but 99% of my logcat contains the message:  "Unknown window type: ..." There's tens of thousands of these in my logcat and I don't know why.

```
06-14 15:34:27.022 2719-2831/? E/WindowManager: Unknown window type: 2014
06-14 15:34:27.022 2719-2831/? E/WindowManager: Unknown window type: 2000
06-14 15:34:27.022 2719-2831/? E/WindowManager: Unknown window type: 2008
06-14 15:34:27.022 2719-2831/? E/WindowManager: Unknown window type: 2000
06-14 15:34:27.022 2719-2831/? E/WindowManager: Unknown window type: 2033
06-14 15:34:27.022 2719-2831/? E/WindowManager: Unknown window type: 2000
06-14 15:34:27.022 2719-2831/? E/WindowManager: Unknown window type: 2011
06-14 15:34:27.022 2719-2831/? E/WindowManager: Unknown window type: 2000
```

What does this mean and why does it appear so much?

Comment: Is this on an actual device, or emulator? Do these messages only happen when your app is running? I've seen a lot of devices that just have log spam.

Comment: this is on an actual device (Galaxy s5), for the genymotion emulator (Galaxy S5), I get... "Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?".. It seems that  Unknown window type errors appear in my logcat on every app on my actual device

Comment: Probably just have to filter it out when you're looking at logs for that phone...

Comment: For me, this error occurs when snapchat is running in the background.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this on a Galaxy S5 running Android 6.0.1. At first I thought it was caused by my own app, but apparently all apps spam this when moving between foreground and background.